# How to compute $\dim_R(\hom_A(U,V))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a $R$-algebra. Let $U,V$ be $A$-modules.
How to compute $\dim_R(\hom_A(U,V))$?

Thanks to every one!

Comment: Which dimension do you mean?

Comment: That is just what I confused?

Comment: We must require $U,V$ be $R$-vector space?

Comment: It is meaningful if $R$ is a finitely generated free $R$ module and $U,V$ are  finitely generated free $R$ modules, for instance.